# Activator UI: importing a non sbt project or adding a JAVA_MODULE to the root

Tags: sbt, typesafe-activator

I'm using Activator and I want to import an existing X-Y Java project that has one Play module (module `A`). It has this tree:

```
|_**A**
  |_app
    |_view
    |_controller
    |_filters
    |_jobs
    |_services
    |_jobs
    |_services
  |_conf
  |_lib
  |_logs
  |_target
  |_project
  |_public
  |_test
  |_**build.sbt**
|_**web.server**
  |_htmlpages
  |_view
  |_model
  |_node_modules
  |_routes
  |_**app.js**
  |_db.js
  |_global.js
  |_**package.json**
|_**B**
  |_out
  |_src
  |_**B.iml**
|_**C**
  |_out
  |_src
  |_**C.iml**
```

The only component `A` has is `build.sbt`. The other components are all Java, except the last one which is `nodeJS`.

If I tried importing the whole project with all the components, Activator UI shows this error:

```
X-Y doesn't contain a valid sbt project
```

If I import only module `A`, it imports fine, but building the project shows me a list of errors, one of them, read from `stdout`:

```
C:\Users\me\X\A\app\controllers\xyzController.java:3: package X.Y.C does not exist
```

Any idea how to import the whole project with all components, or how to add all other components to the already imported `sbt` component `A`?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use SBT's [multi-project build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Multi-Project.html). Specifically, you need to have a project for each module you want to build into your final project. Practically, this means that you need a `build.sbt` file in a root directory, under which all your other modules exist. (Note that it's fine that some of the projects are not on the JVM.)

Your directory structure will look something like this:

```
/root-project-name
  /moduleA
    /src
      /app
        /controller
        /filter
        /... (all module A app files)
  /moduleB
    /src
      / ... (all module B files)
  /moduleC
    /src
      / ... (all module C files)
  /build.sbt
```

In your `build.sbt` you'll declare each of the projects separately:

```
 lazy val moduleA = (project in file("moduleA")).dependsOn(moduleB)

 lazy val moduleB = (project in file("moduleB"))
```

The `dependsOn` clause lets `moduleA` reference `moduleB`. You only have to create a `project` variable for any modules that you plan on building with SBT - so you can leave your Javascript project out, for instance.